# Find first occurrence of value in a range, going up

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a column as follows,

```
1
2
2
1
3
4
5
```

how would I find the first occurrence of a particular number going upwards from a known value, say 4. I know the position of 4 in the column and I want the row number of the first occurrence of 1 going upwards from 4 (row number 4 in this case).

My instinct was to run a FOR loop but I think there's a fairly straightforward method to this that I'm not familiar with.

Appreciate the help!

p.s - I realise another way to find this would be to find the last occurrence of a value in a range going from the first row to the position of 4. Happy to learn either or both.

Comment: Suppose values are in range,, B2:B8 then excel formula `LOOKUP(2,1/($B$2:$B$8=4),ROW($B$2:$B$8))` will return row number of first 4 from bottom. If its index/position in the values is needed then `result-Row(B1)`.If needed in VBA, the same formula could be evaluated.

Comment: For reference, https://exceljet.net/how-to-lookup-first-and-last-match

Comment: @Nathan_Sav it does but thanks for the response. I don't understand this formula but I'll learn it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sheet1.Range("M:M").Find(What:="1", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=Range("M12")).Address
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd just learned how to use the .find method to find the position of 4 in this example but was unfamiliar with the various optional arguments that can be given in it. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Just so I can understand htis method better, .find method returns any occurrence of the argument right? For example if there was a 16 instead of the 1, it would still return the same position because the value contains a "1". And if this is true then this is where i use l"ookat := xlwhole", right?

Comment: @Wren that is correct you will use LookAt:=xlWhole to find complete string

Comment: Yep, I tried it out. Seems to work. thanks a lot!